# How Can I Utilize full Features Of media Player In Jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

Iam Using media Player for audio In my app But Iam not able to play audio smoothly in my app emulator sometimes some unwanted voices are coming is this normal or should I need to do SomeThing
and where can I learn more about media Player In JetPack compose

Answer (score 0):

learn about ExoPlayer. It's the player youtube uses, this will smoothly run your songs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34376842)